# Dynamics 365 for Operations trial instance: Write custom code

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

How can I write plugins, workflows or JS for trial instance of Dynamics 365 for Operations using Visual Studio, like we do for MS Dynamics CRM online instance?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately in Dynamics 365 Operations we cannot write plugins but we can create an out of box custom functionality known as "Developer Tools Addin" for performing any kind of functionality in a short and smooth way. The way to write the code is completely available in C#.

Microsoft has tried to bring X++ very close to the semantics of C# as now it as well has been counted in the list of .Net Compliant Languages.

Answer (score 0):

No, We cannot write plugins, workflows, JS in Operations like CRM.

Dynamics 365 for Operations (AX) is totally different ball game when compared to Dynamics CRM ([wrt architecture & stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/operations/dev-itpro/dev-tools/application-stack-server-architecture)).

Dynamics 365 for Operations is using x++ (.xpp) for custom developments & comparison with C# [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/operations/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-cs-comparison)

We have used Sharepoint as web client for AX, bcoz that time only thick client was available for AX. In that front, Dynamics 365 for Operations come up with strong Azure stack in cloud space.